# How to access a nested hash value when performing a sql query in Rails?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, join

The column with the nested hash looks like this and I would like to access *language* key from the *subscription* column

```
=> #<User:0x00007fc609916ac8
 id: "224cc26e-6a66-43a0-96db7d3775ac",
 name: "Jack Ryan",
 email: "jack@ryan.com",
 subscription: {"plan"=>"paid", "language"=>"English", "country"=>"Germany" },
```

Would appreciate any help on this. Thanks

I have tried accessing it in few different ways but keep getting error

```
ActionView::Template::Error (PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column users.subscription['language'] does not exist
```

```
ActionView::Template::Error (PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column users.subscription.language does not exist
```

```
ActionView::Template::Error (PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column users.subscription[:language] does not exist
```

Comment: Share you migration file you used to create `User`

Answer (score 0):

you can use [store_accessor](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Store.html) for this, so, you can configure the hash attribute like this (in your model):

```
store_accessor :subscription, %W(plan language country)
```

and that will generate proper attr_accessor's for the hash keys.